# Max range in interval for good numbers

Tags: python

So I am trying to find the maximum length of good numbers in a range that takes into account bad numbers. For example, if I have 2 and 5 for the intervals and my bad numbers are 1, 2, and 3, then my max length would be 2 (4-5). I am having compilation issues at the moment and have tried enumerate, declaring as string, but I am getting nowhere fast and a little assistance would be most appreciated:

```
def bad(a,b,x):
    max_x = max(x)
    y = range(a, b+1)
        if max_x in y:
           print(len(y) - max_x)
        else: 
           print(y)
numbers = input().split()
m = numbers[0]
n = numbers[1]
x = str(numbers[2:])

bad(m,n,x)
```

If I attempt to run this, I get the following compilation errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 13, in <module>
    bad(m,n,x)
  File "Solution.py", line 3, in bad
    y = range(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: what exactly are good and bad numbers?

Comment: Give example of exact inputs and exacts outputs, supplemented with proper description what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Input: 1 10 1 5 8 2 3 20
Output: 2

So, the interval is 1 to 10 including 1 and 10, the bad numbers are 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, and 20, 20 is not in the range, so the range is only 2 (9 to 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: you need to convert your inputs from `str` to `int`, and you then you need to fix the logic you're using for figuring out the distance between a point in a range and the end of the range.

The rest of this answer will be me walking through how I approach debugging problems like this.  :)

When I'm trying to understand how a function works, it's very important to understand the types of the inputs that it expects, and the type of result it will return (if any).  Simply writing this down in the form of comments or a docstring is often enough -- what are `a`, `b`, and `x`?  The debugging process will go a lot easier if you declare this up front, since you can then look for cases that don't match that declaration.

From reading through your function implementation, I'm inferring that `a` and `b` are the endpoints of the range, and bad numbers are defined by a list `x`.  I'm going to not only document that but also add *type annotations* to the function:

```
from typing import List


def bad(a: int, b: int, x: List[int]) -> None:
    """Print the length of the longest range of numbers
    that lies between a and b but does not include any of x."""
    max_x = max(x)
    y = range(a, b+1)
    if max_x in y:
        print(len(y) - max_x)
    else:
        print(y)


numbers = input().split()
m = numbers[0]
n = numbers[1]
x = str(numbers[2:])

bad(m, n, x)
```

The great thing about type annotations is that machines can understand them.  I'm going to ask my best Python buddy [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if it sees anything wrong with how I'm using this function, given the way I've declared it:

```
% mypy bad.py
bad.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
bad.py:20: error: Argument 2 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
bad.py:20: error: Argument 3 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "List[int]"
```

So: all of my input arguments are `str`, when we want `a` and `b` to be `int`s, and we want `x` to be a `List[int]` (a `List` of `int`s.)

How is that happening?  I can use `reveal_type` to find out what the types of different variables are:

```
numbers = input().split()
reveal_type(numbers)
```

```
% mypy test.py
bad.py:16: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.str]'
bad.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
bad.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
bad.py:21: error: Argument 3 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "List[int]"
```

Okay, so `numbers` isn't a list of `int`s, it's a list of `str`s!  Let's fix that:

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
reveal_type(numbers)
```

```
% mypy bad.py
bad.py:16: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.int*]'
bad.py:21: error: Argument 3 to "bad" has incompatible type "str"; expected "List[int]"
```

Hey, now it's a `List[int]` -- and two of our errors went away, because now `m` and `n` are `int`s!  Let's fix the last one (all we need to do is remove the `str` conversion, since `numbers` is already the right type for what we want to do) and then remove that `reveal_type` since we don't need it any more:

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
m = numbers[0]
n = numbers[1]
x = numbers[2:]

bad(m, n, x)
```

```
% mypy bad.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Okay, now let's see if our code actually works:

```
% python bad.py
2 5 1 2 3
1
```

Hm, not quite.  I think the mistake here is that the inclusive range from 2 to 5 has an overall length of 4, and so you're taking the difference between 4 and 3 (the highest number you want to exclude).  What you want is instead the difference between the end of the range (5) and 3.

```
def bad(a: int, b: int, x: List[int]):
    """Print the length of the longest range of numbers
    that lies between a and b but does not include any of x."""
    max_x = max(x)
    y = range(a, b+1)
    if max_x in y:
        print(b - max_x)
    else:
        print(y)
```

```
% python bad.py
2 5 1 2 3
2
```

This is a little better, but how about some other test cases?

```
% python bad.py
2 5 0
range(2, 6)

% python bad.py
2 5 5
0
```

Both of these seem wrong -- the first one should give me `4` (the whole range, since it contains no bad numbers) and the second one should give me `3` (the length of the range from 2 to 4).

Just so I don't have to keep on typing these test cases out as I work on fixing them, I'm going to build them into my script, and I'm going to change the function so it returns the result instead of just printing it (that way I can check it inside the script):

```
from typing import List


def bad(a: int, b: int, x: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return the length of the longest range of numbers
    that lies between a and b but does not include any of x."""
    max_x = max(x)
    y = range(a, b+1)
    if max_x in y:
        return b - max_x
    else:
        return len(y)


# Quick test to assert that my function works before I let the user try it.
assert bad(2, 5, [1, 2, 3]) == 2
assert bad(2, 5, [0]) == 4
assert bad(2, 5, [5]) == 3

numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
m = numbers[0]
n = numbers[1]
x = numbers[2:]

print(bad(m, n, x))
```

Oh hey, now mypy tells us about an error it didn't spot before (because it didn't know that the answer was supposed to be an `int`):

```
% mypy bad.py
test.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "range", variable has type "int")
```

So let's fix that up by changing `return y` to `return len(y)`, which I'm not sure is correct, but it's the most obvious way to turn a `range` into a single `int`.  We'll see in a second whether that works.  Now mypy passes again and I can try my test cases:

```
% python bad.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert bad(2, 5, [5]) == 3
AssertionError
```

Hey, just my quick guess of changing `y` to `len(y)` fixed the `[0]` case!  So now we just have the case where the bad number is closer to the end of the range and we want the range to be **everything before the smallest bad number**.  It's kind of the same as what we're already doing, just on the other side.

```
def bad(a: int, b: int, x: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return the length of the longest range of numbers
    that lies between a and b but does not include any of x."""
    min_x = min(x)
    max_x = max(x)
    y = range(a, b+1)
    if min_x in y and max_x in y:
        return max(b - max_x, min_x - a)
    elif min_x in y:
        return min_x - a
    elif max_x in y:
        return b - max_x
    else:
        return len(y)
```

That fixes all of our test cases!  I'll leave one more for you as extra credit:

```
assert bad(1, 100, [2, 99]) == 96
```

Good luck!  :)

Comment: I like your explanations for each part, however when I run this with the following variables: 1 10 5 4 2 15, I get an answer of 1 instead of the expected 5. I am wondering if I have something wrong in my calculations. I tried to replicate what you put down, but had an error with the **x: List[int]) -> int:** portion due to the List or even numbers, which was my original input list not being recognized by the function (not defined)

Edit: Just found this at the top of your code **from typing import List**....facepalm

Comment: Make sure you did the `from typing import List`, and if you're on Python 2, upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: I actually just caught that and confirmed that it removed that error, but for some reason, the scenario still returns 1 instead of 5, but the operations seem accurate.

Comment: And yes, there is another bug in there, which is that you're taking `max_x` before you check to see which parts of `x` are in the range `y`.  :)  Try `max(n for n in x if n in y)`.  Or: just filter down `x` up front since you don't care about bad numbers outside the range.  `x = [n for n in x if n in y]`, or `x = [n for n in x if a <= x <= b]`.  Something like that.  Then `max(x)` and `min(x)` will return the values you want.

Comment: That works now, thank you so much for your assistance. I am still trying to grasp the basics and intermediate features of Python and detailed, explained answers like these help novices like me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue with the input not being converted to integers.

```
numbers = input().split()
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
```

Comment: Well, the reason why I did my input for x that way is I am not sure of the number of bad numbers given. I have incorporated this into my code in the following:


    numbers = input().split(" ")
m = numbers[0]
n = numbers[1]
x = [int(x) for x in numbers]
bad(m,n,x)

I am wondering if this is the correct location as I am still receiving the following error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 12, in <module>
    bad(m,n,x)
  File "Solution.py", line 3, in bad
    y = range(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str